# I deleted /etc/init.d/redis-server.. how do I get it back?

Tags: linux, debian

I was following some instructions for how to fully remove gitlab so I could re-install from scratch, I deleted `/etc/init.d/redis-server` and now the new git installation is broken because it's not there. I tried to `apt-get` install/remove redis-server but it says it already exists. Any way to regenerate that init.d script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal and type as

```
sudo dpkg --configure redis-server
```

If that method doesnt fix then do as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall redis-server
```

that will regenerate .

hope that helps.

Comment: That's what I tried first but it didn't work :/ In the end this worked for me: `sudo apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove redis-server -y` and then `sudo apt-get install redis-server`

Comment: @bruchowski we glad about your issue resolved but 2nd command also can help you. read apt-get man page for --reinstall command.

Comment: the `--reinstall` option didn't regenerate the `/etc/init.d/redis-server` file, I checked after running it

Answer (score 0):

it is located under redis $HOME under utils

cp utils/redis_init_script /etc/init.d/redis_6379`enter code here`